# How can I configure Acrobat so that it runs a Acrobat Javascript script whenever a PDF is opened in Acrobat?

Tags: pdf, javascript, adobe-acrobat, pdf-reader

I wrote an Acrobat Javascript script. How can I configure Acrobat so that it runs a Acrobat Javascript script whenever a PDF is opened in Acrobat?

---

> What have you tried?

I looked around in the Acrobat menu.

> What make you believe it is possible?

That'd make sense to be able to configure Acrobat so that it runs a Acrobat Javascript script whenever a PDF is opened in Acrobat.

> Have you inserted your script into a PDF?

No, this is an [Acrobat Javascript script](https://evermap.com/javascript.asp). This has nothing to do with [inserting JavaScript within a PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9640141/395857).

Comment: Closevoters: what's unclear?

Comment: Read https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/javascript_console/  https://acrobatusers.com/forum/javascript/how-run-script-docopen-event/

and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134134/run-javascript-in-pdf-when-document-opens

Comment: @Gantendo thanks, great read! Too bad the question is currently closed and nobody can't write an answer for it

Comment: Oh well, problem solved, that is what matters. Have a great day!

Comment: @Gantendo true but the question will get automatically removed if left closed. Which means if I forget what the answer is, then I'll have to search for the answer again. I opened a meta question:  [What's unclear about this question on how to configure Acrobat so that it runs an Acrobat Javascript script whenever a PDF is opened?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14626/116475)

Comment: Sorry I need 3k reputation to re-open it. But I assume someone else will come along and re-open it because an answered question must have enough details and clarity to be answered.

Comment: @Gantendo np, good thing you'll soon hit 3k.

Comment: @Gantendo the question was reopened, would you like to convert your comment into an answer? Otherwise I'll do it. thanks!

Comment: Sure, but I'll use your wording because you are more eloquent than I am!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Tools>JavaScript>Document JavaScripts` and add your Acrobat Javascript script there. They should run at open. If you need to make sure that the PDF is fully loaded before the Acrobat Javascript script starts to execute, you can [amend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33143221/395857) your Acrobat Javascript script accordingly.